# NLog MessageBox target not found

Tags: nlog

I am unable to use the NLog MessageBox target in a WinForm application.  The config file indicates the xsi:type is invalid.  When I run the program I get this error:

> System.TypeInitializationException
>    HResult=0x80131534
>    Message=The type initializer for 'Catalog.Form2' threw an exception.
>    Source=Catalog
>    StackTrace:
>     at Catalog.Form2..ctor() in L:\SourceCode\Catalog\Catalog\Form2.cs:line 29
>     at Catalog.Program.Main() in L:\SourceCode\Catalog\Catalog\Program.cs:line 16
>
> Inner Exception 1:
>   NLogConfigurationException: Exception when parsing L:\SourceCode\Catalog\Catalog\bin\Debug\NLog.config. 
>   Inner Exception 2:
>   ArgumentException: Target cannot be found: 'MessageBox'

My config file contains this:

```xml
<targets>
  <target name="errors" xsi:type="MessageBox" layout="${message}" />
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="errors" />
</rules>
```

If I change the target to "Console" everything works.  Why does MessageBox not work?

NLog 4.5.11,
NLog.Schema 4.5.11,
.NET Framwork 4.7.2,
VS 2017 Pro (15.9.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the MessageBox  target you need to install the [NLog.Windows.Forms NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Windows.Forms/).

See also: https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=targets&search=messagebox

[image]